# Issue with jQuery Autocomplete and Sticky Footer

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, footer, sticky-footer

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/n3mcH/

I use http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html .

The footer is attached to the bottom, but if you type in the input field "j" for example, when the autocomplete popup appears the footer is not more attached to the bottom, instead there's now a white space.

How to solve?

Comment: True, in Chrome works well. The issue is in Firefox 8.0.1, Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm... very odd bug.  I'm not sure how it affects the other browsers (especially opera), but for chrome and FF adding this rule seems to help... thought it may not be a viable solution.

```
.ui-autocomplete{position:absolute !important;}
```

Comment: Neat guy! This seems to fix the bug (even in Opera). Thanks!